# Prove $f(z)$ is continuous at $z_o$ iff its real and imaginary parts are continuous at $z_o$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Was wondering if I could get some suggestions/second looks at my proof where $f(z) = f(x +iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x,y).$ I'm not sure about the right direction especially show $u, v$ are continuous.

($\implies$)

Suppose $f(z)$ is continuous at $z_o = x_o + iy_o$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ so that if $|z - z_o| < \delta$ then $|f(z) - f(z_o)| < \epsilon$.

Note that:

$|u(x, y) - u(x_o, y_o)|, |v(x, y) - v(x_o, y_o)| \leq |f(z) - f(z_o)| \leq |u(x, y) - u(x_o, y_o)|+ |v(x, y) - v(x_o, y_o)|$

Since $f(z) - f(z_o) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) - [u(x_o, y_o) + iv(x_o, y_o)] = [u(x,y) - u(x_o, y_o)] +i[v(x,y) - v(x_o, y_o)]$

And we know that $|Re z|, |Imz| \leq |z| \leq |Rez| + |Imz|$.

Since $|(x,y) - (x_o, y_o)| \leq |z-z_o| < \delta$ then $|u(x, y) - u(x_o, y_o)| \leq |f(z) - f(z_o)| < \epsilon$ and so $u(x, y)$ is continuous at $z_o$.

Similarly, since $|(x,y) - (x_o, y_o)| \leq |z-z_o| < \delta$ then $|v(x, y) - v(x_o, y_o)| \leq |f(z) - f(z_o)| < \epsilon$ and so $v(x, y)$ is continuous at $z_o$.

($\impliedby$)

Suppose $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ are continuous. Then for $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 > 0, \exists \delta_1, \delta_2 > 0$ so that if $|(x,y) - (x_o, y_o)| < \delta_1$ then $|u(x,y) - u(x_o, y_o)| < \epsilon_1$. Likewise, if $|(x,y) - (x_o, y_o)| < \delta_2$ then $|v(x,y) - v(x_o, y_o)| < \epsilon_2$.

Let $\epsilon > \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 > 0$ and take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$. Then if $|z - z_o| < \delta$ this means $|(x,y) - (x_o, y_o)| < |z -
 z_o| < \delta_1, \delta_2$ so we have:

$|f(z) - f(z_o)| \leq |u(x,y) - u(x_o, y_o)| + |v(x,y) - v(x_o, y_o)| < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 < \epsilon \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \square$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct but a little long.

Also you don't need different $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ ,just  fix an $\epsilon>0$ and work with it all the way.

> Now for a simpler approach you could just use directly that if $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ then $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)$
>
> and the fact that $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{z \to z_0}\Re{f(z)}+i\lim_{z \to z_0}\Im{f(z)}$.

Now i don't know if you have been asked to solve this only with  epsilon-delta.

If so then you are fine.

Just be a little more careful with the epsilon usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not sure why I picked two epsilons now that I look at it that seems pretty bad. I do need two deltas though because that will probably be different for $u,v$?

Comment: @danny Yes indeed you need two deltas ..in this part you were  absolutely correct..this is the crusial part of the proof.to notice or understand  that the deltas may be different.